# Testing FIRDataSnapshot in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xctest

In my current setup I have only one constructor (and want to keep it that way) for my domain objects. Say my class looks like this:

```
class Person: FIRDataObject //my custom class

let name: String
let age: Int

required init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    self.name = snapshot.json["name"].string
    self.age = snapshot.json["age"].int
}
```

..and now I want to test my class. But I can't find any way to instansiate a new FIRDataSnapshot from my test. F.ex I would like something like

```
class PersonTest: XCTest

   test_create_person() {
       let snapshot = FIRDataSnapshot("{name: "Kim", "age", 33}") <-- I want something like this
       let person = Person(snapshot: snapshot)
       XCTAssertEqual(...)
   }
```

Anyone figured out how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way (using SwiftyJson, but thats optional) by subclassing FIRDataSnapshot. Please let me know if you find a better one:

```
class PersonTest: XCTest

    test_create_person() {
        let person = Person(snapshot: FIRPersonDataSnapshot())
        XCTAssertEqual(person.name, "Kim")
    }

class FIRPersonDataSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot

    override var value : Any? {
        let json: JSON = [
            "name": "Kim",
            "age": 33,
        ]
        return json.dictionaryObject
    }
```